# Laravel: Override SoftDeletes trait properly

Tags: php, laravel, soft-delete

I want to make a trait that uses `SoftDeletes` named `SoftDeletesWithStatus` that will also update the status column. My problem is that I want to implement my code in the middle of `SoftDeletes`'s functions like that:

```
protected function runSoftDelete() {
    $query = $this->newQueryWithoutScopes()->where($this->getKeyName(), $this->getKey());
    $time = $this->freshTimestamp();
    $columns = [$this->getDeletedAtColumn() => $this->fromDateTime($time)];

   //I want to implement my code here

    $this->{$this->getDeletedAtColumn()} = $time;
    if ($this->timestamps && ! is_null($this->getUpdatedAtColumn())) {
        $this->{$this->getUpdatedAtColumn()} = $time;
        $columns[$this->getUpdatedAtColumn()] = $this->fromDateTime($time);
    }
    $query->update($columns);
}

public function restore() {
    if ($this->fireModelEvent('restoring') === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->{$this->getDeletedAtColumn()} = null;

    //I want to implement my code here

    $this->exists = true;
    $result = $this->save();
    $this->fireModelEvent('restored', false);
    return $result;
}
```

Is it a better solution that copy pasting the code in my `SoftDeletesWithStatus` trait and implement my code in it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can't do it without copy it and modify it you could add it to a baseModel and extend your model to that class ..  if you tell us what are you trying to do maybe we can help

Comment: I want to do soft deletes (you know, with the `deleted_at` column) but that also updates the custom `status` column (i.e. status 99 is deleted, status 1 is activated).

Comment: @Bader Why the downvotes though?

Comment: sorry not me I like your answer btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JacupoStanchis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9658326/jacopostanchi) solution is not complete in my opinion.
Relations are not getting handled by the the methods `runSoftDelete` and `restore` of the new trait.

Assume you have a simple relation like:
`Author 1-n Book`

Working example:

```
$Author->delete();
$Author->restore();
```

Not working example:

```
$Book->author()->delete();
$Book->author()->restore();
```

Thanks to Xdebug i could figure out a solution for the "not working example".
*BTW. In my case there was a need of a string column so i could make use of the unique constraint in combination with the deleted state. So the methods differ.*

`app/Traits/SoftDeletes.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use App\Overrides\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope;

trait SoftDeletes
{
    use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

    /**
    * Boot the soft deleting trait for a model.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public static function bootSoftDeletes()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new SoftDeletingScope);
    }

    /**
    * Perform the actual delete query on this model instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    protected function runSoftDelete()
    {
        $query = $this->newModelQuery()->where($this->getKeyName(), $this->getKey());

        $time = $this->freshTimestamp();

        $columns = [
            $this->getDeletedAtColumn() => $this->fromDateTime($time),
            $this->getDeletedHashColumn() => uniqid(),
        ];

        $this->{$this->getDeletedAtColumn()} = $time;

        if ($this->timestamps && ! is_null($this->getUpdatedAtColumn())) {
            $this->{$this->getUpdatedAtColumn()} = $time;

            $columns[$this->getUpdatedAtColumn()] = $this->fromDateTime($time);
        }

        $query->update($columns);
    }

    /**
    * Restore a soft-deleted model instance.
    *
    * @return bool|null
    */
    public function restore()
    {
        // If the restoring event does not return false, we will proceed with this
        // restore operation. Otherwise, we bail out so the developer will stop
        // the restore totally. We will clear the deleted timestamp and save.
        if ($this->fireModelEvent('restoring') === false) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->{$this->getDeletedAtColumn()} = null;
        $this->{$this->getDeletedHashColumn()} = '';

        // Once we have saved the model, we will fire the "restored" event so this
        // developer will do anything they need to after a restore operation is
        // totally finished. Then we will return the result of the save call.
        $this->exists = true;

        $result = $this->save();

        $this->fireModelEvent('restored', false);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
    * Get the name of the "deleted at" column.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getDeletedHashColumn()
    {
        return defined('static::DELETED_HASH') ? static::DELETED_HASH : 'deleted_hash';
    }

}
```

`app/Overrides/Eloquent/SoftDeletingScope.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Overrides\Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent;

class SoftDeletingScope extends Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope
{

    /**
    * Extend the query builder with the needed functions.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
    * @return void
    */
    public function extend(Eloquent\Builder $builder)
    {
        foreach ($this->extensions as $extension) {
            $this->{"add{$extension}"}($builder);
        }

        $builder->onDelete(function (Eloquent\Builder $builder) {
            $deletedAtColumn = $this->getDeletedAtColumn($builder);
            $deletedHashColumn = $builder->getModel()->getDeletedHashColumn();

            return $builder->update([
                $deletedAtColumn => $builder->getModel()->freshTimestampString(),
                $deletedHashColumn => uniqid(),
            ]);
        });
    }

    /**
    * Add the restore extension to the builder.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
    * @return void
    */
    protected function addRestore(Eloquent\Builder $builder)
    {
        $builder->macro('restore', function (Eloquent\Builder $builder) {
            $builder->withTrashed();

            return $builder->update([
                $builder->getModel()->getDeletedAtColumn() => null,
                $builder->getModel()->getDeletedHashColumn() => '',
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

I added the `bootSoftDeletes` method to the new Trait which adds the custom `SoftDeletingScope` to the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I've come to the solution is:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

//Status 1 = Activated; Status 99 = Deleted
trait SoftDeletesWithStatus {
    use SoftDeletes {
        SoftDeletes::runSoftDelete as parentRunSoftDelete;
        SoftDeletes::restore as parentRestore;
    }

    public function getStatusColumn() {
        return defined('static::STATUS') ? static::STATUS : 'status';
    }

    public function runSoftDelete() {
        $this->parentRunSoftDelete();
        $query = $this->newQueryWithoutScopes()->where($this->getKeyName(), $this->getKey());
        $columns = [$this->getStatusColumn() => 99];
        $this->{$this->getDeletedAtColumn()} = 99;
        $query->update($columns);
    }

    public function restore() {
        $result = $this->parentRestore();
        $this->{$this->getStatusColumn()} = 1;
        $this->save();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

And then I simply use my trait in the models I want:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\SoftDeletesWithStatus;

class MyModel extends Model {
    use SoftDeletesWithStatus;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an idea, why the trait is being ignored when deleting through relationship?

Comment: @GordonFreeman I am facing the same problem. Reason is HasRelationship checks if model is using `SoftDelete` and inserts `whereNull` query. You also need to override `SoftDeletingScope` classes `apply` method.

Comment: @MikeRoss Thanks for the info. Feel free to edit my answer :) Otherwise I'll check it an a few days